# Как при помощи flex'ов или grid'ов воссоздать поведение float'ов

Tags: html, css, bootstrap, flexbox, css-grid

```css
.row {
  display: flex;
  // display: block;
  // display: grid;
}

.container {
  max-width: 1200px;
  width: 100%;
  padding-right: 15px;
  padding-left: 15px;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
}

.row {
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  margin-right: -15px;
  margin-left: -15px;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.col-4 {
  flex: 0 0 33.33333%;
  max-width: 33.33333%;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 1px;
  padding-right: 15px;
  padding-left: 15px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  float: left;
}

[class*="bl"] {
  background-color: #d7d7d7;
  height: 150px;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 50px;
}

.bl1 {
  height: 330px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-4">
            <div class="bl1">1</div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-4">
            <div class="bl2">2</div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-4">
            <div class="bl3">3</div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-4">
            <div class="bl4">4</div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-4">
            <div class="bl5">5</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Эксперты нужна ваша помощь[image: ![введите сюда описание изображения]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M9pe2.png)
Бьюсь весь вечер, как добиться результата как на картинки?

Answer (score 0):

Flex

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.flex {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 400px;
  height: 200px;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  margin: auto;
}

.item {
  background: lightblue;
  border: 4px solid #fff;
}

.item1 {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}

.item2,
.item3,
.item4,
.item5 {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex">
  <div class="item item1">1</div>
  <div class="item item2">2</div>
  <div class="item item3">4</div>
  <div class="item item4">3</div>
  <div class="item item5">5</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Grid

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.grid {
  width: 600px;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 200px 200px 200px;
  grid-template-areas: "item1 item2 item3" "item1 item4 item5";
  margin: auto;
}

.item1,
.item2,
.item3,
.item4,
.item5 {
  background: lightblue;
  border: 4px solid #fff;
}

.item1 {
  grid-area: item1;
}

.item2 {
  grid-area: item2;
}

.item3 {
  grid-area: item3;
}

.item4 {
  grid-area: item4;
}

.item5 {
  grid-area: item5;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="item1">1</div>
  <div class="item2">2</div>
  <div class="item3">3</div>
  <div class="item4">4</div>
  <div class="item5">5</div>
</div>
```